# React - state. Изменение объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу изменить переменную в state.
Есть state =

```
id: '',
avatar: '',
steps: 0,
programName: '',
programDate: '',
programPrice: '',
personalInfo: {
  name: '',
  surname: '',
  sex: 'man',
  birthDay: '',
  birthMonth: '',
  birthYear: '',
  familyStatus: '',
  countryBirth: '',
  cityBirth: '',
  birthCitizenship: '',
  currentCitizenship: ''
},
```

как в теперь мне изменить например `this.state.personalInfo.name` ??

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
 setState({
    personalInfo: {
        ...this.state.personalInfo,
        name: 'LOL'
    }
})
```